# unable to display section as flex inside of grid div

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to display a div of sections inside of a grid layout but unfortunately the sections only display as block. I am hoping someone will be able to tell me how to display the second portion of the data flexed, currently when I try to select the div inside of Class locationInfo as display flex it does nothing at all.

I want it to look like [image]

but currently it looks like the following
[image]

here is my component

```
<template>
  <div id="mainDiv">

        <div id="locationInfo">
               <!-- left detail section -->
            
                  <div>
                    <section>
                    <p><b>NYC</b></p>
                    <small>7:35</small>
                    </section>
                  
                  <section>
                    <img src='../assets/svg/flight.svg' height="40px" width="40px"/>
                    <small>10/12/20</small>
                    </section>
                
                <section>
                    <p><b>SYD</b></p>
                    <small>10:45</small>
                  </section>

                      <div id="AirlinesDetails">
               <img src="../assets/svg/home/logo-2.svg" height="40px" width="40px" />
                  <section>
                    <b><p>Turkish Airlines</p></b>
                    <small>cx511 | Airbus 333</small>
                  </section>
                  <section>
                    <p>2 Stop</p>
                    <small>3h 58min</small>
                  </section>
                </div> 

             </div>
        



        <!-- second row-->
                  <div>
                    <section>
                      <h4>NYC</h4>
                      <small>7:35</small>
                    </section>

                    <section>
                      <img src='../assets/svg/flight.svg' height="40px" width="40px"/>
                      <small>10/19/20</small>
                    </section>
                 
                    <section>
                    <h4>SYD</h4>
                    <small>10:35</small>
                    </section>

                        <div id="AirlinesDetails">
               <img src="../assets/svg/home/logo-2.svg" height="40px" width="40px" />
                  <section>
                    <b><p>Turkish Airlines</p></b>
                    <small>cx511 | Airbus 333</small>
                  </section>
                  <section>
                    <p>2 Stop</p>
                    <small>3h 58min</small>
                  </section>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              </div>
        
       

        </div>
    
  </div>
</template>


<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
#modal-1{
  border: none;
  color: black;
}
#modal-1 div{
  border: none;
  padding-right: 1em;
  
}
#modalInputdiv1{
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}
#modalInputdiv1 div{
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#modalInputdiv1 input{
  width: 40%;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
}
#modalInputdiv1 input::placeholder{
  padding-left: .5em;
  color: black;
}
#modalInputdiv2{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

#modalInputdiv2 input::placeholder{
  padding-left: .5em;
  color: black;
}
#modalInputdiv2 div{
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: .5em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
}
#modalInputdiv3{
display: flex;
justify-content: left; 
border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
padding-left: .5em;
}
#modalInputdiv3 div{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);

}
#modalSaveDiv{
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#modalsaveBtn{

  background-color:#2E9CFF;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90%;
}

#dob{
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
  width: 50%;
}

.modalImg{
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
#modalInputdiv2 input{
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
}

.modaldivs{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 40%;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.349);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#modalInputdiv2 p{
  margin-top: .5em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 .5em;
}
#modalInputdiv2 img{
  margin-top: .5em;
  
}
.blocked{
  display: block;
}
.blockedflex *{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.flexed{
  display: flex;
}

.toggleSectionActive{
  color: #288EF9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #51D79D;
}
#toggleSections{
  background-color: white;
}

#sideBarDiv{
  justify-content: center;
  padding:.5em;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0a78f5, #59B0FF);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #88888877;
}
#flyexlogo {
 margin-right:1em;
}
#sideBarDiv div{
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.sideBarDivicons{
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 2em;
}


#mainDiv{
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(73, 79, 90);
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:#F8F8FF;
  border-radius: 10px; 
}

#bodyGrid{
  margin: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4% 60% 30%;
}

#middleCol div{
margin: .5em;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
}

#middleCol section{
text-align: left;
margin: 1em 1.5em 1em 1.5em;
}
#middleCol section small{
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #BCC0C7;
}

#middleCol section h5:hover{
color: #288EF9;
}
#detailsDiv{
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.158);
}
#detailsDiv div{
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.384);

}
.detailsDivHeaderSection{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 margin-left:3em;
}
.detailsDivHeaderSection p{
 margin-left:1em;
 margin-right:2em;
}

#leftTripDetails{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#change{
color: #288EF9;
}

#locationInfo{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
#locationInfo div{
width: 45%;
display: flex;

}



#locationInfo div img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
 display: block;
}

#locationInfo small{
  color:rgb(54, 54, 54);
}

#AirlinesDetails{
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.158);
background-color: white;
}
#AirlinesDetails img{
margin-left: 1em;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
}




#departureandreturnDiv{
  padding: .5em 0 0 .5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.158);
  background-color: white;
}
#departureandreturnDiv p{
  padding-right: 2.5em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  color: #BCC0C7;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#departureandreturnDiv p:hover{
  color: #288EF9;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #51D79D;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you specifically want to use grid to achieve the layout?

Comment: I could use a grid or a flex layout it doesn't matter to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this possible solution with flex and see if it helps.

```
 <div class="flight-container">
      <section class="flight">
        <div class="flight-info">
          <div>
            <h4>NYC</h4>
            <p><small>7:35</small><p>
          </div>
          <div>
          <img src='../assets/svg/flight.svg' height="40px" width="40px"/>
          <p><small>10/19/20</small></p>
        </div>
          <div>
          <h4>SYD</h4>
          <p><small>10:35</small></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flight-info">
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div>
                <img src="../assets/svg/home/logo-2.svg" height="40px" width="40px" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong>Turkish Airlines</strong></b>
                <p><small>cx511 | Airbus 333</small><p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4>2 Stop</h4>
            <p><small>3h 58min</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="flight">.....</section>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.flight-container{
  display: flex;
}
.flight{
  width: 50%;
}
.flight-info{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row{
  display:flex;
}
```

Comment: ah yes that did help me solve it thank you :)